# Removing Duplicates within Quicksight Analysis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, duplicates, amazon-quicksight

I am using Quicksight and looking for some help with removing data duplicates from a joined table. Here is more information.

I'm in charge of the eligibility of a user receiving a gift card (it was from a promotion). At the end of the week, we will have to find users who have referred and are still active within the application to receive the gift card. This is done by comparing the status of an Excel spreadsheet of the "base" data and the weekly spreadsheet given. The first data/base data, we'll call it data1, contains the vital information id, name, email, status, etc. The second data has the same columns only with added users (i.e. more rows).

However, there may be duplicates where the gift cards have been given out (based on the data 1 info) to a user but it still appears in the new weekly sheet generated, data 2, with the exact same information. To prevent duplication of the gift cards, we would like to eliminate the this issue.